# bringing filtered lists in model to view

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, jpa-2.0

My spring-mvc-hibernate application has three lists of `Pet` objects (`pets`, `cats`, `dogs`) which are populated in the model (an `Owner` class) and need to be sent to the view (a jsp mapped to the /owners url pattern) by the controller (OwnerController.java). All three of the lists should be populated from the same `pets` table in the underlying database, with the `pets` list including all listings in the `pets` table, and the `cats` list only including those entries from the `pets` table which are cats, and the `dogs` list only including those entries from the `pets` table which are dogs.  ***The problem is that all three lists are being populated with ALL pets regardless of types.***  I have confirmed via System.out.println() commands that ***the problem with list population is occurring at the level of the model***.  How can I get the `cats` list to only include cats and the `dogs` list to only include dogs?

Here is relevant code from the model, Owner.java:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner")
private Set<Pet> pets;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Pet> cats;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Pet> dogs;

protected void setPetsInternal(Set<Pet> pets) {this.pets = pets;}

// Call this from OwnerController before returning data to page.
public void parsePets() {
    for (Pet pet : getPetsInternal()) {
        if (pet.getType().getName().equals("cat")) {
            cats.add(pet);
            System.out.println(pet.getType().getName());
            System.out.println("cats.size() is: "+cats.size());
            System.out.println("added a cat to cats");
        } 
        else if (pet.getType().getName().equals("dog")) {
            dogs.add(pet);
            System.out.println(pet.getType().getName());
            System.out.println("dogs.size() is: "+dogs.size());
            System.out.println("added a dog to dogs");
        }
        // add as many as you want
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
      }
    }

public Set<Pet> getCats() {
    System.out.println("about to return cats");
    for (Pet cat : cats) {System.out.println("counting a "+cat.getType()+" in cats.");}
    System.out.println("cats.size() is: "+cats.size());
    return cats;
}

public Set<Pet> getDogs() {
    System.out.println("about to return dogs");
    for (Pet dog : cats) {System.out.println("counting a "+dog.getType()+" in dogs.");}
    System.out.println("dogs.size() is: "+dogs.size());
    return dogs;
}

protected Set<Pet> getPetsInternal() {
    if (this.pets == null) {this.pets = new HashSet<Pet>();}
    return this.pets;
}

public List<Pet> getPets() {
    List<Pet> sortedPets = new ArrayList<Pet>(getPetsInternal());
    PropertyComparator.sort(sortedPets, new MutableSortDefinition("name", true, true));
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(sortedPets);
}
```

Here is relevant code from the controller, OwnerController.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/owners", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String processFindForm(@RequestParam("ownerID") String ownerId, Owner owner, BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> model) {
    Collection<Owner> results = this.clinicService.findOwnerByLastName("");
    model.put("selections", results);
    int ownrId = Integer.parseInt(ownerId);
    Owner sel_owner = this.clinicService.findOwnerById(ownrId);
    sel_owner.parsePets();
    model.put("sel_owner",sel_owner);
    return "owners/ownersList";
}
```

And here is relevant code from the view jsp, note that each of the three dandelion datatables are the same except that each is devoted to a separate list, either pets, cats, or dogs:

```
<datatables:table id="pets" data="${sel_owner.pets}" cdn="true" row="pet" theme="bootstrap2" 
                  cssClass="table table-striped" paginate="false" info="false"  filter="false"
                  cssStyle="width: 350px;" align="left" >
    <datatables:column title="Name" cssStyle="width: 200px;" display="html">
        <c:out value="${pet.name}"/>
    </datatables:column>
    <datatables:column title="BirthDate" cssStyle="width: 300px;" display="html">
        <joda:format value="${pet.birthDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    </datatables:column>
    <datatables:column title="Type" cssStyle="width: 200px;" display="html">
        <c:out value="${pet.type.name}"/>
    </datatables:column>
</datatables:table>

<datatables:table id="cats" data="${sel_owner.cats}" cdn="true" row="cat" theme="bootstrap2" 
            cssClass="table table-striped" paginate="false" info="false"  filter="false"
            cssStyle="width: 350px;" align="left" >
    <datatables:column title="Name" cssStyle="width: 200px;" display="html">
        <c:out value="${cat.name}"/>
    </datatables:column>
    <datatables:column title="BirthDate" cssStyle="width: 300px;" display="html">
        <joda:format value="${cat.birthDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    </datatables:column>
    <datatables:column title="Type" cssStyle="width: 200px;" display="html">
        <c:out value="${cat.type.name}"/>
    </datatables:column>
</datatables:table>

<datatables:table id="dogs" data="${sel_owner.dogs}" cdn="true" row="dog" theme="bootstrap2" 
              cssClass="table table-striped" paginate="false" info="false"  filter="false"
              cssStyle="width: 350px;" align="left" >
    <datatables:column title="Name" cssStyle="width: 200px;" display="html">
           <c:out value="${dog.name}"/>
    </datatables:column>
    <datatables:column title="BirthDate" cssStyle="width: 300px;" display="html">      
        <joda:format value="${dog.birthDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    </datatables:column>
    <datatables:column title="Type" cssStyle="width: 200px;" display="html">
        <c:out value="${dog.type.name}"/>
    </datatables:column>
</datatables:table>
```

---

### EDIT:

When I comment out the @OneToMany annotations preceding cats and dogs, the following error is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException:  
Could not determine type for:  
java.util.Set, at table: owners, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(cats)]
```

Note that Cat and Dog are not defined as classes because, at this point, they do not store different information or methods than pets and I wanted to simplify the code.  Do I need to make a Cat class and a Dog class?  Or can I fix this problem without making separate classes?

---

### SECOND EDIT:

I added @Transactional and commented out //@OneToMany(...) before the declarations of both cats and dogs, but left the @OneToMany(...) annotation in before the declaration of pets.  I also added

```
= new HashSet<Pet>();
```

to the declaration of both cats and dogs.  However, now the application is failing to initialize when I do Run As...Run on Server within eclipse:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  
Error creating bean with name  
'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0'  
defined in class path resource [spring/business-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed;  
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource  
[spring/business-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;  
nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException:  
[PersistenceUnit: petclinic] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
```

The code for business-config.xml [can be read at this link.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/resources/spring/business-config.xml)  Can anyone show me how to fix this problem?

I can eliminate the error message and get the application to run by commenting out the changes, but then I am left with the problem that the three lists (pets, cats, dogs) are identical, when I need cats and dogs to each be different subsets of pets.  Here is the code which eliminates the error message but creates three identical lists which should not be identical:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner",  fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Pet> pets;

//I added next two variables
//    @Transient
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Pet> cats;// = new HashSet<Pet>();

//    @Transient  
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)  
private Set<Pet> dogs;// = new HashSet<Pet>();
```

Comment: Do `Cat` and `Dog` extend some base class?  I'm guessing `Pet`?

Comment: @KevinBowersox Cat and Dog do not exist as classes.  Only Pet is a class.

Comment: is the relationship between `Owner` and `Pet` bidirectional?

Comment: @KevinBowersox One owner can have many pets, but each pet can only have one owner.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the hibernate mapping for the cats and dogs! Only map the (internal) `pets` list via hibernate to the database. And then filter the cats and dogs out (like you already did).

I you want to add pets, then make sure that they are added to the (internal) `pets` list.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner",  fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Pet> pets;

/**
 * Selection of cats from pets, it is a COPY!
 * Lazy populated cache, set it to NULL for invalidation.
 * The set itself is unmodifiable!
 */
@Transient
private Set<Pet> catsCache;

/** the same for dogs: @Transient private Set<Pet> dogsCache; */

public Set<Pet> getPets() {
    return Collections.<Pet>unmodifiableCollection(this.pet);
}

public Set<Pet> getCats() {
    if (this.catsCache == null) {
        Set<Pet> catsSelection = new HashSet();
        for (Pet pet : this.pets) {
           //assume pet.type is an emum called PetType wiht an enumaration cat, if this does
           //not exist, then use: if (pet.getType().getName().equals("cat"))
           if (pet.getType() == PetType.cat)
               catsSelection.add(pet);
        }
        this.catsCache = Collections.<Pet>unmodifiableCollection(catsSelection);
    }
    return this.catsCache;
}

public void addPet(Pet catOrDog) {
    this.pets.add(catOrDog);
    this.catsCache = null;
}
```

Comment: @CodeMed Those fields must be annotated with `@Transient` or else JPA will attempt to map the field.

Comment: @Ralph I added a second edit to my original posting above showing the current error.  Are you willing to spend some time helping me figure this out?  I have been stuck with variations of this problem for a couple days now, and have tried many different approaches without success. If you can write an explicit code solution, you will really educate me.

Comment: @CodeMed: I have added an example

Comment: @Ralph Thank you very much for trying to help. I started to use your code, but eclipse is giving me errors about the fact that there is no Cat class in my application.  Then when I made a clone of the Pet class and renamed it Cat, the errors in your code included things like pet not being able to be cast into cat, and PetType not having a subtype cat.  I could write a lot of complicated code just to test what you added.  Can we just create a list called cats which is populated by the subset of pets that are cats? Based on a hibernate where clause?

Comment: An my, fault, I was thinking that you have an subclass Cat. -- I have modified the code in the example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with your approach make `dogs` and `cats` transients so JPA does not attempt to map the fields or populate them with entities:

```
@Transient
private Set<Pet> cats = new HashSet<Pet>();

@Transient
private Set<Pet> dogs = new HashSet<Pet>();
```

If you wanted to implement `Dog` and `Cat` classes to establish and inheritance relationship you could follow this [tutorial](http://blog-tothought.rhcloud.com/post/21) I have made.

Comment: I added a second edit to my original posting above which more completely describes the current error.  Any ideas?